# nquad giving wrong results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to understand why nquad does not appear to handle large limits very well. In the following I am integrating a normal distribution pdf out to fairly large numbers and it seems to break if either limit is especially large, or if one of the limits is numpy.inf.  I know I can't expect the integrator to be perfect, but I was surprised that this didn't at least return a warning.  I guess I have more to learn about how the integrators work.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy import special


def intFunc(x1):
  val = (1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*np.exp(-(x1**2)/2)
  return val

val=scipy.integrate.nquad(intFunc,[[-np.inf,np.inf]])[0]
print("infinity to infinity val ={}".format(val))
val=scipy.integrate.nquad(intFunc,[[-np.inf,10000]])[0]
print("-infinity to 10000 val ={}".format(val))
val=scipy.integrate.nquad(intFunc,[[-np.inf,60]])[0]
print("-infinity to 60 val ={}".format(val))
val=scipy.integrate.nquad(intFunc,[[-60,60]])[0]
print("-60 to 60 val ={}".format(val))
```

gives

```
integralLimitTest.py
infinity to infinity val =0.9999999999999997
-infinity to 10000 val =0.0
-infinity to 60 val =2.207242645942812e-66
-60 to 60 val =0.9999999999999999
```

Comment: This is a `quad` FAQ; see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656971/scipy-integrate-pseudo-voigt-function-integral-becomes-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193045/why-does-integrate-quadlambda-x-xexp-x2-2-sqrt2pi-0-0-100000-give-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536467/scipy-integrate-quad-not-returning-the-expected-values.  If the interval where your integrand is (numerically) nonzero is small, `quad` might never "see" the nonzero integrand.  Even with its adaptive intervals, it might just see a function that is 0 or only very small.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I guess I was just more surprised that it worked from -inf to +inf than it didn't work for large limits.  Any insight into why that would be the case?